# how to change zenity input separator

Tags: linux, shell, zenity

Is it possible to change `zenity` row (i.e. line) input separator like the option `--separator` changes the output separator?

I know that piping through `tr '\t' '\n'` would help, but is it possible another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator) (IFS) variable.

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Comment: I should have said that it is not the field separator, but the row or line separator that I want to change.
That is, instead of \n I would like to use \t

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
zenity  --list  --width=800 --height=600 --text "$_BACKTITLE" --checklist  --column "ON/OFF" --column "Select Software to add:" --separator ","
```

You can use any separator you like for the output.